# xdvi -copy misses a font

Tags: xdvi

I have a tex file 'file.tex' which has the line

```
    \raisebox{-1pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {1}}}
```

This displays the numeral 1 inside a circle. After latex, the command `xdvi -copy file.dvi` gives an empty circle with no numeral. However `xdvi file.dvi` displays the numeral 1 correctly. My problem is I need the `-copy` option since the file.tex  outputs to over 900 pages with heavy use of mathematics, hyperlinks and diagrams. It would take too long to load without the -copy option. I have no other issues with the output of `xdvi -copy file.dvi`.

I use Debian and my xdvi is part of texlive-2019. I could try upgrading to the latest version of texlive but I would rather like a more immediate solution.

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example what shows your problem. Then others can easily copy the code and test it. May I ask why you are still using `dvi`? Post people usedirect  PDF nowadays

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `xdvi`:

```
-copy  (.copy)  Always use the copy operation when writing characters to the dis-
       play.  This option may be necessary for correct operation on a color  dis-
       play,  but  overstrike  characters  will be incorrect.  If greyscale anti-
       aliasing is in use, the -copy operation will disable  the  use  of  color-
       planes and make overstrikes come out incorrectly.  See also -thorough.
```

Overstriking refers to printing characters one above the other, which is the case of `\textcircled`. So this is documented. Don't use `-copy`.